# How to drop multi temporary table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to drop multiple temporary table from SQL Server
Below code give this error :
 msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'drop'.

```
  declare @deptno int = 1
 while @deptno > (Select COUNT(*) from tbl_deptseat)+1
 Begin
   Declare @deptnamevar nvarchar(20) = '##dept'+ cast(@deptno as nvarchar(10))
    exec (drop table (@deptnamevar))
End
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 declare @deptno int = 1
```

`while @deptno < (Select COUNT(*) from tbl_deptseat)+1
   Begin
   Declare @deptnamevar nvarchar(20) = '##dept'+ cast(@deptno as nvarchar(10))
   Declare @dropquery  nvarchar(20) = 'drop table '+ @deptnamevar
   exec (@dropquery) 
   set @deptno = @deptno + 1
   End`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very strange way of approaching data processing.  I wouldn't recommend putting such logic in *table names*.  Instead, the logic belongs in columns.

But, you want to use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @deptno int = 1;
declare @sql nvarchar(max);
while @deptno < (Select COUNT(*) from tbl_deptseat)+1
Begin
   Declare @deptnamevar nvarchar(20) = '##dept'+ cast(@deptno as nvarchar(10));
   set @sql = 'drop table ' + @deptnamevar;
   exec(@sql) ;
   set @deptno = @deptno + 1;
End;
```